# Need Help In Php Mysqli Html Form

Tags: php, html, file, file-handling

I want to make a form in which when I upload my text file it will appear in the `textarea` box (the content of the txt csv file to be printed in the `textarea` box). I have done a web search but didn't get any idea.

Answer (score 0):

The new JS File API can help you.

If you dont need the file uploaded on your serveur, then take a look [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).
You'll just need to adapt it a little to make it fill the value of your input box (maybe you should use a textarea instead of a simple input here).

If you need upload:

- How to handle file upload: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp
- How to read file content and put it on a string: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-get-contents.php

If I was you, I would make two scripts. The first one handle upload and redirect to the second one, wich show a page (or the same form as the previous) with the text field updated.

Comment: i want to upload file and later the text of file display in textbox is there any script you know >? because i want to import email from the text file.

Comment: So you want to process the file server side ?

Comment: yes sir ^_^ you are right now i dont know what to do any help >?

Comment: I dont have any already-done script, I can just redirect you to some good sources. (I'm editing my response)